# How to test UI of website?

Tags: user-interface, testing, automation, automated-tests

I want to check the presence of Portlets, Image, Video, Text, Dropdowns, Radio Buttons/Check-boxes, Linking of Pages, behavior of links/images(whether the link is opening in current window or new window is opened) and all possible scenarios for website testing. 
For look and feel I will compare it with mockups. And I am entering all the content via Content Management System(CMS).
I need to automate all this stuff.

Which open-source tools should I use other than Selenium?
Can I do all this with Selenium?

If scripting is required please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question. Selenium should do all of this, but you will need to do some scripting to make it all work. Can you break this into smaller, more narrowly scoped questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Selenium. It does not require scripting as long as your test cases are linear, i.e. the service you are testing behaves so that you can run the same tests many times and the system always responds in the same way when it comes to those things you want to check.

Selenium is scriptable, but it can be used without scripting.

As long as your web site is based on HTML/XML Selenium works well. It doesn't work with Flash components and such.

Comment: Thanks Antti... I forgot to mention but my website do have Java Applet component(EditLive)...

Answer (score 2):

If you're not scoping specifically to Open Source, but instead free tools, then you might consider [Telerik's Testing Framework](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/free-testing-framework.aspx). It's free with commercial variants for tooling and support. It's got great cross-browser support, handles OS-level dialogs (file upload/download, e.g.) on Windows, and has some great features around AJAX support.

Disclaimer: I'm the evangelist for Test Studio.

Comment: +1 I've used both Selenium and the Telerik testing framework, both can do the job very well.

Answer (score 0):

The first and most important thing about the testing your are trying to do on the app is , no matter what tool you use , the best UI Testing can be done only by the humans . Provided with the condition that you are trying to check the look and feel of the app.As no Testing Tool in the world can do the UI testing better than Human.

**So I would suggest that you better go for Manual User Interface (UI) testing rather than Automation.**

Comment: Manual and exploratory testing is a critical part of any large system's successful delivery; however, automation is a critical piece of that too. You shouldn't throw out automation for manual. It's a careful balance of both.